# Passing variables from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html

I have made a table filled with database-fields including a checkbox. (1 DB-entry per tablerow).
if i select some entries (by clicking on a checkbox) i want to delete those ones.

I have to pass those db-key entry-values from the table, to PHP. So i can delete that DB-entry with the right db-key.

How can i do that ?

I just wanna use HTML-table-entries in my PHP-script."

Comment: Using a form or AJAX?

Comment: Since you didn't specify anything else, it would be `<form>` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use post.

```
<form name="deleteThisForm" method="POST"><!-- be sure to include the method="post" attribute-->
    <input name="ID" type="radio" value="1"/>
    <input name="submitDelete" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['submitDelete']){
    //mysqli connection etc
    $delete=$DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM this WHERE ID=?");
    $delete->bind_param('i',$_POST['ID']);
    $delete->execute();
    return'deleteled successfully.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would wrap the table in a `<form>` tag, and then have a check box per row with that row’s database identifier as the value. For example:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="1" /></td>
```

Then, have a script that takes a `POST` request and delete from your database the records with the passed IDs.

```
<?php

foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $id) {
    if (preg_match('/^([0-9]+)$/', $id)) {
        // logic to delete from the database
    }
}
```